# Get the name of the Data Extension you are working with : Custom Activity

Tags: marketing-cloud, javascript, journeybuilder, custom, custom-activity

I'm developping a custom activity in NodeJS and I would like to know how can I get the name of the Data Extension I'm working with to put the name here :

```
payload['arguments'].execute.inArguments = [{
            'campaignNameKey': campaignNameKey,
            'csvName': csvName,
            "Prenom": "{{Contact.Attribute.DE_NAME.Prenom}}",
            "Nom": "{{Contact.Attribute.DE_NAME.Nom}}",
            "Mobile": "{{Contact.Attribute.Contacts.Mobile}}",
            "Campagne": "{{Contact.Attribute.Contacts.Campagne}}",
            "stopSMS": "{{Contact.Attribute.Contacts.stopSMS}}"
        }];
```

For the moment, I'm using the name of my test Data Extension ("Contacts") but I would like to be able to use this payload on any Data Extension. Thanks !

EDIT : my customActivity.js

```
define(function (require) {
var Postmonger = require('postmonger');
var connection = new Postmonger.Session();
var payload = {};
var steps = [
    {'key': 'eventdefinitionkey', 'label': 'Event Definition Key'}
];

//HERE it works 
//connection.trigger('requestSchema');

var currentStep = steps[0].key;
var deName;
$(window).ready(function () {
    connection.trigger('ready');
});

function initialize(data) {
    if (data) {
        payload = data;
    }
}

function onClickedNext() { //SAVE USED HERE
    if (currentStep.key === 'eventdefinitionkey') {
        save();                       
    } else {
        connection.trigger('nextStep');
    }
}

function onClickedBack () {
    connection.trigger('prevStep');
}

function onGotoStep (step) {
    showStep(step);
    connection.trigger('ready');
}

function showStep (step, stepIndex) {
    if (stepIndex && !step) {
        step = steps[stepIndex - 1];
    }

    currentStep = step;

    $('.step').hide();

    switch  (currentStep.key) {
    case 'eventdefinitionkey':
        $('#step1').show();
        $('#step1 input').focus();
        break;
    }
}



function save() { //SAVE FUNCTION
    console.log('save');
    connection.trigger('requestSchema'); //NOT SHOWN IN CONSOLE

    let campaignNameKey = $('#select-campaign-name').val();
    let csvName = $('#select-csv-name').val();

    console.log("DE NAME " + deName);
    payload['arguments'] = payload['arguments'] || {};
    payload['arguments'].execute = payload['arguments'].execute || {};

    payload['arguments'].execute.inArguments = [{
        'campaignNameKey': campaignNameKey,
        'csvName': csvName,
        "Prenom": "{{Contact.Attribute."+ deName +".[\"Prénom\"]}}",
        "Nom": "{{Contact.Attribute." + deName +".Nom}}",
        "Mobile": "{{Contact.Attribute." + deName +".Mobile}}",
        "Campagne": "{{Contact.Attribute." + deName +".Campagne}}",
        "stopSMS": "{{Contact.Attribute." + deName +".stopSMS}}"
    }];

    payload['metaData'] = payload['metaData'] || {};
    payload['metaData'].isConfigured = true;
    //console.log(JSON.stringify(payload));
    connection.trigger('updateActivity', payload);
}

connection.on('requestedSchema', function (data) {    //CONNECTION ON
    // save schema
    console.log('*** Schema ***', JSON.stringify(data['schema']));
    let schema = JSON.stringify(data['schema']);
});
connection.on('initActivity', initialize);
connection.on('clickedNext', onClickedNext);
connection.on('clickedBack', onClickedBack);
connection.on('gotoStep', onGotoStep);
});
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use undocumented 'requestSchema' [Postmonger](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-app-development.meta/mc-app-development/using-postmonger.htm) event to retrieve schema of event data source:

```js
connection.trigger('requestSchema');
```

Than use response from Journey Builder:

```js
connection.on('requestedSchema', function (data) {
   // save schema
   console.log('*** Schema ***', JSON.stringify(data['schema']));
});
```

Extract relevant information and save it in inArguments.
 
Example of schema:

```js
[{
    "key": "Event.APIEvent-cbf6ce98-ba4f-a5c1-cc68-503ca1f60c39.Id",
    "type": "Text",
    "length": 18,
    "default": null,
    "isNullable": null,
    "isPrimaryKey": null
}, {
    "key": "Event.APIEvent-cbf6ce98-ba4f-a5c1-cc68-503ca1f60c39.Name",
    "type": "Text",
    "length": 50,
    "default": null,
    "isNullable": null,
    "isPrimaryKey": null
}, {
    "key": "Event.APIEvent-cbf6ce98-ba4f-a5c1-cc68-503ca1f60c39.Mobile",
    "type": "Text",
    "length": 50,
    "default": null,
    "isNullable": null,
    "isPrimaryKey": null
}]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot that was exactly what I've been searching for ! :)  I will ask you a further question if you don't mind : Can I get the colmns names of a Data Extension with those kind of trigger ? And if possible which one ?

Comment: Event.APIEvent-cbf6ce98-ba4f-a5c1-cc68-503ca1f60c39.Id in my solution Id is a column name, so you need just extract this data from the schema.

Comment: I edited the question and there is the answer of requestedSchema, I don't see the same structure of JSON as you have

Comment: My bad mate ! It was just that I was not seeing the good thing because of Journey Builder and the save feature that didn't take the correct customActivity.js thanks a lot !

Comment: I am using API Event as entry source, so i have different schema

Comment: Sorry a last question : I don't understand why the connection.trigger works when it is outside of my function save (in customActivity.js) and not working in it, I'm doing the same thing but when it is outside of the save function it is shown in the console.

Comment: I'm sure that it is a little problem but I don't see it :/

Comment: it will work only in root level of your script, store it in variable than use it on save.

Comment: This is a true golden nugget - I've been looking *literally* for months for this. We were having the toughest time dealing with the different payloads from a data extension associated with a synced SF data source vs. a Salesforce Data event trigger DE. Amazing, this changes everything. Thank you ‍♂️

Answer (score 6):

You can use requestedTriggerEventDefinition Postmonger event, it will return a schema that will return information about the Journey builder(Name,dataExtensionId,...) to you.

You need the field eventDefinitionKey and use it instead of your data extension 'Contacts'.

Here is an example of what it would be like

```
var eventDefinitionKey;
connection.trigger('requestTriggerEventDefinition');

connection.on('requestedTriggerEventDefinition',
function(eventDefinitionModel) {
    if(eventDefinitionModel){

        eventDefinitionKey = eventDefinitionModel.eventDefinitionKey;
        console.log(">>>Event Definition Key " + eventDefinitionKey);
        /*If you want to see all*/
        console.log('>>>Request Trigger', 
        JSON.stringify(eventDefinitionModel));
    }

});
```

And then in function save :

```
payload['arguments'].execute.inArguments = [{
    'campaignNameKey': campaignNameKey,
    'csvName': csvName,
    "Prenom": "{{Contact.Attribute."+ eventDefinitionKey+".\"Prénom\"}}",
    "Nom": "{{Contact.Attribute." + eventDefinitionKey+".\"Nom\"}}",
    "Mobile": "{{Contact.Attribute." + eventDefinitionKey+".\"Mobile\"}}",
    "Campagne": "{{Contact.Attribute." + eventDefinitionKey 
    +".\"Campagne\"}}",
    "stopSMS": "{{Contact.Attribute." + eventDefinitionKey +".\"stopSMS\"}}"
}];
```

Answer (score 2):

You may also use requestInteraction which is part of the Postmonger events.

```
var eventDefinitionKey;
connection.trigger('requestInteraction');

connection.on('requestedInteraction', function(settings){
    eventDefinitionKey = settings.triggers[0].metaData.eventDefinitionKey;
});
```

So in your function **save** you can use the eventDefinitionKey variable to reference to your entry source DE

```
payload['arguments'].execute.inArguments = [{
  "campaignNameKey": campaignNameKey,
  "csvName": csvName,
  "Prenom": "{{Event."+ eventDefinitionKey +".Prenom}}",
  "Nom": "{{Event."+ eventDefinitionKey +". Nom}}",
  "Mobile": "{{Event."+ eventDefinitionKey +". Mobile}}",
  "Campagne": "{{Event."+ eventDefinitionKey +". Campagne}}",
  "stopSMS": "{{Event."+ eventDefinitionKey +". stopSMS}}"
}];
```

For more information:

[Postmonger Events Reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-app-development.meta/mc-app-development/using-postmonger.htm)

Comment: Hey man! can you help me on this, I tried your solution & did not work : https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/372479/retrieve-fields-from-dynamic-data-extention-in-custom-activity

Comment: I tried to execute the requestInteraction to get the defintion key, and used the CONTACT object to get my rows fields from the DE using CONTACT.ATTRIBUTE.DE_NAME but now, I replaced the DE_NAME with the defintion key & it is not correct, is there a way I can retirieve the DE name ?