# Custom Activity - Retrieve Platform Data

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, custom-activity

guys!

Just to provide a brief overview of what we're working on, we have a business case where he needs to use a custom activity in Journey Builder. We are using a data extension as an input and a data source to execute the journey, and we want some data extension fields to be retrieved by the custom activity so that we can use that data in a call to a sending service.

We are following the documentation at https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-app-development.meta/mc-app-development/example-rest-activity.htm | https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/how-data-binding-works.htm and so far we have not been successful.

These fields I want to retrieve from the data extension, '**EmailAddress**', '**Phone**' and '**Message**'.

'**Config.json**' to bind the data:

```
    {
  "workflowApiVersion": "1.1",
  "metaData": {
    "icon": "images/icon.png",
    "category": "message"
  },
  "type": "REST",
  "lang": {
    "en-US": {
      "name": "Send WhatsApp",
      "description": "Send a whatsApp message.",
      "step1Label": "Configure WhatsApp"
    }
  },
  "arguments": {
    "execute": {
      "inArguments": [
        {
          "phone": "{{Contact.Attribute.NameDataExtension.phone}}"
        },
        {
        "email": "{{InteractionDefaults.Email}}"
        }
      ],
      "outArguments": [],
      "url": "https://urltest.herokuapp.com/journeybuilder/execute",
      "verb": "POST",
      "useJwt": true,
      "timeout": 10000
    }
  },
  "configurationArguments": {
    "applicationExtensionKey": "c1009dfa-eb0b-48c5-8521-3c8da1e34bb9",
    "save": {
      "url": "https://urltest.herokuapp.com/journeybuilder/save",
      "verb": "POST",
      "useJwt": true
    },
    "publish": {
      "url": "https://urltest.herokuapp.com/journeybuilder/publish",
      "verb": "POST",
      "useJwt": true
    },
    "stop": {
      "url": "https://urltest.herokuapp.com/journeybuilder/stop",
      "verb": "POST",
      "useJwt": true
    },
    "validate": {
      "url": "https://urltest.herokuapp.com/journeybuilder/validate",
      "verb": "POST",
      "useJwt": true
    }
  },
  "wizardSteps": [
    { "label": "Configure Activity", "key": "step1" }
  ],
  "userInterfaces": {
    "configModal": {
      "height": 400,
      "width": 1000,
      "fullscreen": false
    }
  },
  "schema": {
    "arguments": {
      "execute": {
        "inArguments": [],
        "outArguments": []
      }
    }
  }
}
```

'**Activity.js**' Where would I look for the data retrieved from the platform and use it for another call.

```
'use strict';
var util = require('util');

// Deps
const Path = require('path');
const JWT = require(Path.join(__dirname, '..', 'lib', 'jwtDecoder.js'));
var util = require('util');
var http = require('https');
var axios = require('axios');

exports.logExecuteData = [];

function logData(req) {
    exports.logExecuteData.push({
        body: req.body,
        headers: req.headers,
        trailers: req.trailers,
        method: req.method,
        url: req.url,
        params: req.params,
        query: req.query,
        route: req.route,
        cookies: req.cookies,
        ip: req.ip,
        path: req.path,
        host: req.host,
        fresh: req.fresh,
        stale: req.stale,
        protocol: req.protocol,
        secure: req.secure,
        originalUrl: req.originalUrl
    });
    console.log("body: " + util.inspect(req.body));
    console.log("headers: " + req.headers);
    console.log("trailers: " + req.trailers);
    console.log("method: " + req.method);
    console.log("url: " + req.url);
    console.log("params: " + util.inspect(req.params));
    console.log("query: " + util.inspect(req.query));
    console.log("route: " + req.route);
    console.log("cookies: " + req.cookies);
    console.log("ip: " + req.ip);
    console.log("path: " + req.path);
    console.log("host: " + req.host);
    console.log("fresh: " + req.fresh);
    console.log("stale: " + req.stale);
    console.log("protocol: " + req.protocol);
    console.log("secure: " + req.secure);
    console.log("originalUrl: " + req.originalUrl);
}

/*
 * POST Handler for / route of Activity (this is the edit route).
 */
exports.edit = function (req, res) {
    // Data from the req and put it in an array accessible to the main app.
    //console.log( req.body );
    logData(req);
    res.send(200, 'Edit');
};

/*
 * POST Handler for /save/ route of Activity.
 */
exports.save = function (req, res) {
       // alert("Save");
    // Data from the req and put it in an array accessible to the main app.
    //console.log( req.body );
    logData(req);
    res.send(200, 'Save');
};

/*
 * POST Handler for /execute/ route of Activity.
 */
exports.execute = function (req, res) {

        var aArgs = req.body.inArguments;
        var oArgs = {};
        for (var i=0; i<aArgs.length; i++) {
            for (var key in aArgs[i]) {
                oArgs[key] = aArgs[i][key];
          console.log('oArgs[key]:'+oArgs[key]);
            }
        }
        console.log('>>>>> req.body: ' + req.body );
        console.log('>>>>> req.body.inArguments: ' + req.body.inArguments );

        var phone = oArgs.phone;
        var email = oArgs.email;

        console.log('>>>>> phone: ' + phone );
        console.log('>>>>> email: ' + email );

let data = ({
            "destinations": [{
                                "correlationId": "MyCorrelationId",
                                "destination": "5511*********"
                            },
                            {
                                "correlationId": "MyCorrelationId",
                                "destination": "5511*********"
                            }],
            "message": {
                "messageText": "<Message here>",
            },

         });

    axios({
      method: 'post',
      url: "https://api-messaging.movile.com/v1/whatsapp/send",
      data: data,
      headers: {'UserName': 'test@test.com.br',
                'AuthenticationToken': '_token_here_',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
    }).then( (res) => {
        console.log("Success -->" , res);
    } )
    .catch( (error) => {
        console.log("Erro --> ", error);
    } );

};


/*
 * POST Handler for /publish/ route of Activity.
 */
exports.publish = function (req, res) {
   // alert("Publish");
    // Data from the req and put it in an array accessible to the main app.
    //console.log( req.body );

    logData(req);
    res.send(200, 'Publish');
};

/*
 * POST Handler for /validate/ route of Activity.
 */
exports.validate = function (req, res) {
   // alert("Validate");
    // Data from the req and put it in an array accessible to the main app.
    //console.log( req.body );
    logData(req);
    res.send(200, 'Validate');
};
```

I really needs to understand how to recover this data and make it work ...
Sorry for any mistake.

Comment: Can someone reply for below question https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/370274/if-10-customers-entered-into-journey-i-need-to-pass-10-customers-data-in-single

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your customActivity;js, you should have a function save() where your payload is setup and ready to send it to your backend server.
If you want to retrieve data from a contact passing by your custom activity, you have to use special expressions like : {{Event.ID.column}} or {{Contact.Attribute.column}} [the official doc](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/how-data-binding-works.htm).
When a contact will pass by your activity, those expressions will be evaluated for your contact so for example if you have a contact with a value : "example@gmail.com". You need to put in the payload something like this :

```
payload['arguments'].execute.inArguments = [{
        'emailAdress': "{{Event.ID-DE.EmailAdress}}"
    }];
```

So when your contact send his payload to the server, the expression will be in `req.body.inArguments[0].emailAdress` and be evaluated at : "example@gmail.com". If you need an example of working custom activity, I highly recommend to you [this example of Markus Slabina](https://github.com/mslabina/sfmc-servicecloud-customsplit) which is great to understand the logic.

If you don't know where to have your dataExtension ID look at [this exchange](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/221821/get-the-name-of-the-data-extension-you-are-working-with-custom-activity).
I hope this will help you

Comment: Thank you, Pierre!
Really just needed to add this information in custom activity.
I was able to retrieve the data from the platform and use them in my REST call.

Comment: Np, I'm glad that it helped you :)