# Journey builder custom activity app accessing Data Extension field values dynamically

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, dataextensions

I have a query regarding marketing cloud custom journey builder app.
This question might look similar and tried but the solution ins't working might be something wrong with my execution. Please correct me here.

Have created an custom app and tried accessing email address from DE through journey builder which was successful accessed but when trying to access other fields, I am not able to do so.

I cannot use DE name to access the fields, since DE and its columns can be different in multiple journeys.

So to solve this, I am asking user to give the column name in popup form text box, then on saving the journey by user customActivity.js is mapping the columns to access the fields given text box dynamically.

Here is my code in customActivity.js on save function to access email address which is working fine.

```
"email": "{{InteractionDefaults.Email}}"
```

similarly while access other fields it not working like for example.

```
"firstname": "{{InteractionDefaults.firstname}}"


* firstname is the exactly same column name in DE which is not accessible.
```

I believe, email address is accessible because journey builder setting in Default Email Address section where in I have to select email attribute from entry source (in my case DE)

Also I have done contact builder mapping with DE column.

Can you please help me with this issue and tell me the correct way to access other fields of DE through custom journey builder app without using the name of DE.

Thanks

Pritam More

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your assumption about the Interaction Defaults is correct. To access entry data you need the Journey/Interaction Context.

This [developer documentation page](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/how-data-binding-works.htm) describes how it works.

I hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for pointing out the document. It helped me and I was able to successfully get the column values using the Event Context method and from solution given here https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/221821/get-the-name-of-the-data-extension-you-are-working-with-custom-activity

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Could you please mark the question as solved so that others find this easier when searching