# Retrieve fields from dynamic data extention in Custom activity?

Tags: marketing-cloud, javascript, journeybuilder, dataextensions, custom-activity

I am having little issue :

in my js script I am trying to push some data dynamically :

```
/**
 * Save settings
 */
function save() {
    //if($form.valid()) {
        payload['metaData'].isConfigured = true;

        var amount = document.getElementById("amount").value;
        var endDate = document.getElementById("end-date").value;

        console.log(eventDefinitionKey)
        
        payload['arguments'].execute.inArguments = [
            {
                "contactKey": "{{Contact.Key}}",
                "age": "{{Contact.Attribute."+eventDefinitionKey+".age}}", // DE can be dynamic
                "country": "{{Contact.Attribute."+eventDefinitionKey+".country}}",
                "details": { amount, endDate }
            }
        ];

        connection.trigger('updateActivity', payload);

    //}
}
```

I am trying to retrieve the eventDefinition key using the requestSchema action :

```
var eventDefinitionKey;

connection.trigger('requestTriggerEventDefinition');
connection.on('requestedTriggerEventDefinition',
function(eventDefinitionModel) {
    if(eventDefinitionModel){

        eventDefinitionKey = eventDefinitionModel.eventDefinitionKey;
        console.log(">>>Event Definition Key " + eventDefinitionKey);
        /*If you want to see all*/
        console.log('>>>Request Trigger', 
        JSON.stringify(eventDefinitionModel));
    }

});
```

I see that the eventKey definition is full in console.log but I am not getting the country field from my DATA EXTENTION when I am trying to update another DE

Issue is in this line, payload is not filled with country : `"country": "{{Contact.Attribute."+eventDefinitionKey+".country}}",`

If I try to not make this dynamic and use name of my DE, it works :

`"country": "{{Contact.Attribute.DE_NAME.country}}",`

So how can I make this dynamic ?

WHOLE custom activity script :

```
'use strict';

const validateForm = function(cb) {
    // $form = $('.js-settings-form');

    /*$form.validate({
        submitHandler: function(form) { },
        errorPlacement: function () { },
    });
    */

    // cb($form);
};

const connection = new Postmonger.Session();
let authTokens = {};
let payload = {};
var eventDefinitionKey;
var globalSettings;
let $form;
$(window).ready(onRender);

connection.on('initActivity', initialize);
connection.on('requestedTokens', onGetTokens);
connection.on('requestedEndpoints', onGetEndpoints);

connection.on('clickedNext', save);

/*connection.trigger('requestTriggerEventDefinition');
connection.on('requestedTriggerEventDefinition',
function(eventDefinitionModel) {
    if(eventDefinitionModel){

        eventDefinitionKey = eventDefinitionModel.eventDefinitionKey;
        console.log(">>>Event Definition Key " + eventDefinitionKey);
        /*If you want to see all
        console.log('>>>Request Trigger', 
        JSON.stringify(eventDefinitionModel));
    }

});
*/
connection.trigger('requestInteraction');

connection.on('requestedInteraction', function(settings){
    console.log("settings", settings);
    eventDefinitionKey = settings.triggers[0].metaData.eventDefinitionKey;
});

const buttonSettings = {
    button: 'next',
    text: 'done',
    visible: true,
    enabled: false,
};

function onRender() {
    connection.trigger('ready');
    connection.trigger('requestTokens');
    connection.trigger('requestEndpoints');

    // validation
    /*validateForm(function($form) {
        $form.on('change click keyup input paste', 'input, textarea', function () {
            buttonSettings.enabled = $form.valid();
            connection.trigger('updateButton', buttonSettings);
        });
    });*/
}

/**
 * Initialization
 * @param data
 */
function initialize(data) {
    
    if (data) {
        payload = data;
    }

    const hasInArguments = Boolean(
        payload['arguments'] &&
        payload['arguments'].execute &&
        payload['arguments'].execute.inArguments &&
        payload['arguments'].execute.inArguments.length > 0
    );

    const inArguments = hasInArguments
        ? payload['arguments'].execute.inArguments
        : {};
    
        if(hasInArguments){
            const { amount, endDate } = payload['arguments'].execute.inArguments[0].details;
            document.getElementById("amount").value = amount;
            document.getElementById("end-date").value = endDate;

        }
    /*
    $.each(inArguments, function (index, inArgument) {
        $.each(inArgument, function (key, value) {
            const $el = $('#' + key);
            if($el.attr('type') === 'checkbox') {
                $el.prop('checked', value === 'true');
            } else {
                $el.val(value);
            }
        });
    });

    validateForm(function($form) {
        buttonSettings.enabled = $form.valid();
        connection.trigger('updateButton', buttonSettings);
    });*/
}

/**
 *
 *
 * @param {*} tokens
 */
function onGetTokens(tokens) {
    authTokens = tokens;
}

/**
 *
 *
 * @param {*} endpoints
 */
function onGetEndpoints(endpoints) {
    console.log("endpoints: ",endpoints);
}

/**
 * Save settings
 */
function save() {
    //if($form.valid()) {
        payload['metaData'].isConfigured = true;

        var amount = document.getElementById("amount").value;
        var endDate = document.getElementById("end-date").value;

        // Listen to interaction request trigger to get event def key to distingish and make DE dynamic 
        // {{Event.my-custom-product-entry-event-key.ProductId}} - Event defnition key
        
        console.log("Taoufiq", eventDefinitionKey)
        
        payload['arguments'].execute.inArguments = [
            {
                "contactKey": "{{Contact.Key}}",
                "age": "{{Contact.Attribute."+eventDefinitionKey+".age}}", // DE can be dynamic
                "country": "{{Contact.Attribute."+eventDefinitionKey+".country}}",
                "details": { amount, endDate }
            }
        ];

        /*
        if ( journeyId === "" ){
            // template
        }
        */

        connection.trigger('updateActivity', payload);

    //}
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the value you are attempting to retrieve dynamically is derived from a given EventDefinition, then you should be able to use the following syntax to access that value dynamically:

```
var eventDefinitionKey;
connection.on("requestedTriggerEventDefinition", function (
    eventDefinitionModel
  ) {
    if (eventDefinitionModel) {
      eventDefinitionKey = eventDefinitionModel.eventDefinitionKey;
    }
  });
```

And then in your save function:

```
country: "{{Event." + eventDefinitionKey + '."country"}}'
```

Comment: Correct Sir! Thankks!!